# Using expressions in Text

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to use Text to add some labels to a graph and was wondering if it is possible to use expressions inside Text? Here is a MWE of what I am trying.

```
field = 1.45;
Plot[x, {x, 1, 3}, Epilog -> {Style[Text["H = " field " T", {1.5, 2.5}], 12]}]
```

The problem is that this adds `1.45H=T` to the plot and I want it to add `H=1.45T`.  I have tried converting `field` to a string first and using that instead, but the output is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
field = 1.45;

Plot[x, {x, 1, 3},
 Epilog -> {Style[Text["H = " <> ToString@field <> " T", {1.5, 2.5}], 12]}]
```

[image]

Comment: My pleasure, thanks for acceptance :)

Comment: Or if you want `TraditionalForm`: `Epilog -> {Style[Text[ToString@TraditionalForm[H == field*T], {1.5, 2.5}], 12]}`

Comment: @kguler Thanks for letting me know, I have upvoted the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Bob Hanlon for an alternative solution.  Seeing multiple solutions is a nice way to learn something new about Mathematica

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
field = 1.45;
Plot[x, {x, 1, 3}, Epilog -> Inset[Style[Row[{"H = ", field, " T"}], 12], {1.5, 2.5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 because the `Row`-solution is superior in more complicated cases (`Superscript` etc.).